# Replace fragment with another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity and tow fragments. When application starts I load fragment one in activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have button in fragment one and I want when it was clicked, substitute it with fragment tow (load parent fragment container). The layout of fragment one and tow are like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/replace"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Replace" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I get error and application stops. Is it possible to do in this way?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @F43nd1r I edited the question.

Comment: Now there is a question. But absolutely no information on your problem. We need code and a stacktrace. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post your java code.

Comment: @Masum I see what u want. But I have general question. How can I Substitute one fragment with another by button that is inside fragment one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this code into your fragment button click listener. Something like this

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new YourFragment();
    FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = frgManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.add(R.id.your_fragment_layout, fragment);
    ft.commit();

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put this in your onclicklistner of your button 
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_place, new Second_fragment()).commit();

//second_fragment ---- that you want to inflate:)

Answer (score 0):

try this
 first create a interface . like this:-

```
public interface Communicator 
{
  public void responde();
}
```

Then implements this inteface in your activity.
and write this code for replace first fragment to second.

```
@Override
public void responde(){
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transation  = manager.beginTransaction();
    SecondFragment   secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    transation.replace(R.id.myActivity, secondFragment, "secFrag");
    transation.commit();}
```

After that add code in first fragment

```
Communicator comm;

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
comm = (Communicator)getActivity();}
//button on click
public void onClick(View v) {comm.responde();}
```

hope it will work.

Comment: If we want to send data from one fragment to other then we need this